# The sum of the 9th power of the roots of the equation $x^3+x-1=0$ are:

Tags: roots

Options are as follows:

- $-6$
- $0$
- $1$
- $2$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Is your calculation wrong? What do you exactly need help with? Questions showing no effort tend to be voted down, and will be closed

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas

Comment: Note that $x_i^9=(x_i^3)^3 = (1-x_i)^3$. Using tricks like this will allow you to transform the formula to the form where you can use Vieta's formulae.

Comment: Multiple-choice is not an appropriate format for this site: what evidence do you have that the answer must be in the list?

Answer (score 0):

Let the roots be $a,b$ and $c$. Since all of them satisfies the equation $x^3+x-1=0$,
\begin{align}
a^9+b^9+c^9 &= (1-a)^3+(1-b)^3+(1-c)^3\\
&= -(a^3+b^3+c^3)+3(a^2+b^2+c^2)-3(a+b+c)+3\\
&=-[(1-a)+(1-b)+(1-c)]+3[(a+b+c)^2-2(ab+bc+ca)]-3(a+b+c)+3\\
&=3(a+b+c)^2-6(ab+bc+ca)-2(a+b+c).
\end{align}
Further, [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas) gives $a+b+c$ and $ab+bc+ca$, which can be plugged into the above expression to get the final answer!

Comment: Thanks. Answer is coming out -6.